# about AVL tree insertion operation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

In the standard process of AVL tree insertion, after we insert a new node, we will do adjustment from bottom to top, and during the process, is it possible a sub-tree height increase by one (because of insertion and rotation operation), while the sub-tree (after height increase by one), still have the same height of left/right child? If so, an example is appreciated, and if not, it will be great if anyone could explain why. Thanks. :)

Here is a reference to AVL tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)

regards,
Lin

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Saibot, add reference of AVL tree. I think it is not possible for a tree to increase by 1 while maintain balance (left/right) child has the same height. But I could be wrong, please feel free to advice. If my question still not clear, please let me know which parts not clear. Thanks. :)

Comment: (Short answer: Not possible. A rotation is used if a bigger sub-tree increases in height and yields a sub-tree of the original height. To increase the height of sibling sub-trees, insert more than one node.) Please define names for the nodes and trees involved, as in _…, can both subtrees_ l _and_ r _of one node_ a _<insert your pre- and post-conditions on heights **using the names defined** >_.

Comment: @greybeard, nice catch. Vote up and like your description of when rotation happens, the final result is tree will have the same height of left/right child, but height will not be increased. If rotation is not involved, is it possible to achieve both after insertion (1) tree has the same height of left/right child, (2) overall tree height increase by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible after the insertion to have the left and right child of the sub-tree to remain same with a change in height.

Lets consider a simple example with only <3 nodes in a sub-tree. The possiblities of balance factor are,

- +1  - which is Root node in subtree with 1 Left Child and no Right child
- -1  - which is Root node in subtree with 1 Right Child and no Left child
- 0  - Root node in subtree has 1 node in Right and Left.

For SubTree with Balance factor +1,

- if we insert into the Right, we are ok
- if we insert into the Left, the balance factor changes to 2. So we need to balance the tree in which case the the height of the subtree is changed.

For SubTree with Balance factor -1,

- if we insert into the Left we are ok
- if we insert into the Right, the balance factor changes to -2. So we need to balance the tree in which case the the height of the subtree is changed.

For SubTree with Balance factor 0,

- if we insert into the Left, we are ok. Height is changed for but the child node is changed as well.
- if we insert into the Right, we are ok. Height is changed for but the child node is changed as well.

So, it is not possible to have the height changed and still have same right and left child heights.

Comment: (This answer suffers from the same problem as the question: Every node in a tree can be considered the root of a sub-tree. Without identifying nodes (with the additional information of before or after a modification that might change the root of a set of nodes) or, equivalently, sub-trees, speaking of `the subtree` is entirely ambiguous.)

Comment: You can take the sub-tree explained in the answer as a whole tree. The concept will remain same and you cannot insert with changing the height and still keep the child nodes height intact. If you differ, then please give an example where you can prove that height can be changed of the root node and still keep the heights of the left and right child intact.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab, nice answer, vote up. What is your exact definition of intact, you mean same height of left and right child? Or you mean keep the original balance factor (-1, 0 or +1)?

Comment: @greybeard, nice catch, yes, I mean node, and using node is better. Vote up your comments. If you have any thoughts on my question, appreciate for your advice in advance. :)

Comment: @Lin Ma, intact means same height.

Comment: Thanks Ashraff for the patient to explain to me, mark your reply as an answer and grant the bounty points. :)

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia Binary Tree page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree):

> A balanced binary tree has the minimum possible maximum height (a.k.a.
>   depth) for the leaf nodes, because for any given number of leaf nodes
>   the leaf nodes are placed at the greatest height possible.
>
> One common balanced tree structure is a binary tree structure in which
>   the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more
>   than 1

For example:

This is a balanced tree.

[image]

And if we insert `1` it's height increases by 1. Yet it is a balanced tree again. Because left and right subtrees differ in height no more than 1.

[image]

BTW, AVL tree is a self-balancing binary search tree. So it is not possible to lose balance after insertion. Because after every insertion, tree balances itself by making necessary rotations.

I think you use the term *balanced* wrongly. You consider balanced as no height difference, but it's at most 1 height difference in definition.

Your question:

> In the standard process of AVL tree insertion, is it possible a sub-tree height increase by one (because of insertion and rotation operation), while the sub-tree (after height increase by one), still have the same height of left/right child?

If we would have a tree which has the same height from left and right branches, and if we would insert a node into a leaf node on left branch, height would increase, because height of the tree is `maximum(height(left_branch, right_branch))`. Because after this operation `height(left_branch)` equals to `height(right_branch)+1`. So, they can't be equal.

In short, your precondition is `height(left_branch) == height(right_branch)`

Your operation is `increasing height of left_branch by 1`

So `height(left_branch) == height(right_branch)` condition can't be true anymore.

Comment: Thanks Saibot, vote up. Yes, when I say balance, I mean whether it is possible to have the same height of left and right sub-tree. Actually my question is, in the standard process of AVL tree insertion, is it possible a sub-tree height increase by one, while the sub-tree (after height increase by one), still have the same height of left/right child? Your advice is appreciated and I will correct my original question as well. :)

Comment: @LinMa Let me know if this explanation not enough for you, in that case I can provide examples.

Comment: Thanks Saibot for the details and vote up. :) For your comments, "If we would have a tree which has the same height from left and right branches", I think there is an issue for the assumption here. Before insert the node, the tree could be either left child higher than right child, or vice versa, besides balanced. So, I think your analysis based on this assumption is not 100% correct. I could be wrong, and please feel free to correct me.

Comment: BTW Saibot, my question is more about **after** insert a new node, is it possible the tree increase height by one, while still have the same height of left/right child? And it does not assume **before** insert a new node, whether the tree had a left child higher, right child higher or same height.

Comment: But you say "still have the same height of left/right child?" *still* means, height difference was 0, and will it be 0 again. If height difference is not zero at the beginning, inserting a new node would make it 0, of course. I think you are not clear about what you ask. Maybe you should edit your question provide an example to clearly express yourself?

Comment: Thanks, Saibot. I re-write part of my question, if my question is still not clear, please feel free to let me know, thanks "In the standard process of AVL tree insertion, after we insert a new node, we will do adjustment from bottom to top, and during the process, is it possible a sub-tree height increase by one (because of insertion and rotation operation), while the sub-tree (after height increase by one), still have the same height of left/right child"?

Comment: BTW, for your comments, ""still have the same height of left/right child?" still means, height difference was 0, and will it be 0 again", I mean before insertion, the sub-tree could be balance of +1, 0 or -1, but after insertion, the sub-tree height increase by one, and has balance of 0, whether it is possible? Your advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible and not unusual, if I understand correctly. If you want to be sure that I understand what you ask, please provide tree examples. Explaining it in English is confusing.